# dynamically changing entry value of util:map in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have defined below map definition in spring config file,So I will get the clientList map object.So my question is,i want to change the entry key "java" value based on some other condition.

```
<util:map id="clientList" map-class="java.util.HashMap">

<entry key="java" value="manualtest"/>  
<entry key="C" value="QTP"/>

</util:map>
```

So here,i can do this after getting map object and using if conditions.Is any otherway i can do this in spring config file itself before spring container returns the object?

is it possible to define something like

other bean determines the value of this entry?

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Can you give an example on the conditions?

Comment: this condition based on value from database,suppose take from database if language value as java.then i want to chnage value of that entry

Answer (score 3):

What if you do like this:

```
<util:map id="clientList" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="#{T(com.MyConditionClass).getCorrectKey()}" value="manualtest"/>  
    <entry key="C" value="QTP"/>

</util:map>
```

here `getCorrectKey()` is static method and `(com.MyConditionClass).getCorrectKey()` will be called before spring container is build up, so you want to be careful not to rely on any spring bean in this method since they are not ready yet.

Check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)